# Extracting value from dict in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

**This is my code right now:**

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
import requests
import datetime


def send_msg(msg, env='prod'):
    if env == 'prod':
        BLINKTRADE_API_URL = 'https://api.blinktrade.com'
        BLINKTRADE_API_VERSION = 'v1'
    else:
        BLINKTRADE_API_URL = 'https://api.testnet.blinktrade.com'
        BLINKTRADE_API_VERSION = 'v1'
        TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10
    key = 'mykeyhere'
    secret = 'mysecrethere'
    secret2 = bytearray(secret, 'utf8') #turn secret into bytearray
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    nonce = str(int((time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond/1000000.0) * 1000000))
    nonce = nonce.encode("utf8")
    signature = hmac.new(secret2,  nonce, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'blinktrade_tools/0.1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',       # You must POST a JSON message
        'ApiKey': key,                            # Your APIKey
        'Nonce': nonce,                           # The nonce must be an integer, always greater than the previous one.
        'Signature': signature                    # Use the API Secret  to sign the nonce using HMAC_SHA256 algo
    }
    url = '%s/tapi/%s/message' % (BLINKTRADE_API_URL, BLINKTRADE_API_VERSION)
    return requests.post(url, json=msg, verify=True, headers=headers,).json()



# Request Balance
msg_balance = {
    "MsgType": "U2",
    "BalanceReqID": 1,
}

msg_orders = {
    "MsgType": "U4",
    "OrdersReqID": 930460
}

print(send_msg(msg_balance))
```

**This prints:**

```
{'Responses': [{'ClientID': 90829382, 'MsgType': 'U3', '4': {'BTC_locked': 737697, 'BTC': 737697, 'BRL': 746655, 'BRL_locked': 0}, 'BalanceReqID': 1}], 'Description': 'OK', 'Status': 200}
```

What I need is to get those values "BRL", "BTC". After 4 hours of research i found no solution.

**I have tried:**

```
data = (send_msg(msg_balance))

print(data['Responses'])
```

**So far so good, but i cant manage to get the the BTC and BRL values to use then. How to extract those values?
Thank for your patience.**

Comment: Please read about how python dictionaries work. This is a typical example of a nested dictionary.

Comment: I am reading about it since yesterday, I just fell that I am missing something really silly, I always solve this things on my own, but the solutions a found did not work...

Answer (score 0):

```
data = (send_msg(msg_balance))
print(data['Responses'][-1]['4']['BTC'])
```

**This solved my problem. I just did not understand why [-1] instead of [1].**

Comment: Indexing usually starts from 0. 1st element in a list will be at index 0. So, ```data['Responses'][0]``` will also work.